# Calling a script with parameters in a form

Tags: shell, vb6, vbscript

I have a form that is supposed to call a script upon a button press. I am trying to invoke it via Command Line.  I tested the script in the command line and it works correctly. I can't get the form to run the script in the command shell. Any ideas?

This is the command line string I need ran autonomously by the shell:

```
cscript.exe proc_image.vbs 170.191.XXX.XXX picName C:\PicStorage
```

This is what I have currently have in my On_Click() action in my button:

```
 ShellEx "cscript.exe C:\Scripts\proc_image.vbs" & " 170.191.XXX.XXX" & " picName" & " PicStorage"
```

My goal is to call the script and pass it 3 parameters: an ip address, name of the picture, and final storage destination. My issue is getting the form to execute the above command line in the shell. Thanks

EDIT: Here is the ShellEx Code:

```
              Private Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" _
(ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal lpOperation As String, _
ByVal lpFile As String, ByVal lpParameters As String, _
ByVal lpDirectory As String, ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function ShellExecuteForExplore Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" _

(ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal lpOperation As String, ByVal lpFile As String, lpParameters  As Any, _
lpDirectory As Any, ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long

 Public Enum EShellShowConstants
essSW_HIDE = 0
essSW_MAXIMIZE = 3
essSW_MINIMIZE = 6
essSW_SHOWMAXIMIZED = 3
essSW_SHOWMINIMIZED = 2
essSW_SHOWNORMAL = 1
essSW_SHOWNOACTIVATE = 4
essSW_SHOWNA = 8
essSW_SHOWMINNOACTIVE = 7
essSW_SHOWDEFAULT = 10
essSW_RESTORE = 9
essSW_SHOW = 5
End Enum

 Private Const ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND = 2&
 Private Const ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND = 3&
 Private Const ERROR_BAD_FORMAT = 11&
 Private Const SE_ERR_ACCESSDENIED = 5        ' access denied
 Private Const SE_ERR_ASSOCINCOMPLETE = 27
 Private Const SE_ERR_DDEBUSY = 30
 Private Const SE_ERR_DDEFAIL = 29
 Private Const SE_ERR_DDETIMEOUT = 28
 Private Const SE_ERR_DLLNOTFOUND = 32
 Private Const SE_ERR_FNF = 2                ' file not found
 Private Const SE_ERR_NOASSOC = 31
 Private Const SE_ERR_PNF = 3                ' path not found
 Private Const SE_ERR_OOM = 8                ' out of memory
 Private Const SE_ERR_SHARE = 26


 Public Function ShellEx( _
    ByVal sFIle As String, _
    Optional ByVal eShowCmd As EShellShowConstants = essSW_SHOWDEFAULT, _
    Optional ByVal sParameters As String = "", _
    Optional ByVal sDefaultDir As String = "", _
    Optional sOperation As String = "open", _
    Optional Owner As Long = 0 _
 ) As Boolean
 Dim lR As Long
 Dim lErr As Long, sErr As Long
If (InStr(UCase$(sFIle), ".EXE") <> 0) Then
    eShowCmd = 0
End If
On Error Resume Next
If (sParameters = "") And (sDefaultDir = "") Then
    lR = ShellExecuteForExplore(Owner, sOperation, sFIle, 0, 0, essSW_SHOWNORMAL)
Else
    lR = ShellExecute(Owner, sOperation, sFIle, sParameters, sDefaultDir, eShowCmd)
End If
If (lR < 0) Or (lR > 32) Then
    ShellEx = True
Else
    ' raise an appropriate error: *ERROR CODES GO HERE*
           End If


  End Function
```

Comment: What does the ShellEx call return? A value of 32 or less indicates a specific error. http://www.vbaccelerator.com/codelib/shell/shellex.htm

Comment: Are the IP address, name of the picture, and final storage destination somehow selected or entered by the user? Can you show the rest of your script?

Comment: The IP address, picture name and storage are read in from a registry. ShellEx is a module that enacts commands on the command line. When I run it, nothing is returned, just nothing happens.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed ShellEx was the alias for the Windows ShellExecute function, the Windows ShellExecute returns a long value. Is the ShellEx module code that you have access to? If so you should post that code also.

Comment: will post the ShellEx here shortly

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing `C:\` in your ShellEx command just prior to PicStorage string?